# Why are these views not rendering? Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Building out a project using Angular. The way it's built uses states, and each state is defined in it's own section, for scalability. My home page is rendering but the partials I'm trying to render inside of it are not. Why?

home.js

```
function config($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('simple.home', {
            url: 'home',
            templateUrl: 'app/home/home.tpl.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl as vm'
        })

}

function HomeCtrl($stateParams, $rootScope, $state){
    var vm = this;
}

angular.module('simple.home', [
    'ui.router',
    'simple.home.ratings',
    'simple.home.search_filter'
])

    .config(config)
    .controller('HomeCtrl', HomeCtrl)
;
```

home.tpl.html

```
<div class="yellow" ui-view="search_filter"></div>
<div class="red" ui-view="ratings"></div>

<style>.yellow {background: yellow; height:400px; width:400px;}
    .red {background: red; height: 400px; width: 800px;}
</style>
```

ratings.js

```
function config($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('simple.home.ratings', {
            views: {
                'ratings': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/home/ratings/ratings.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'RatingsCtrl as vm'
                }
            }
        })
}

function RatingsCtrl($modal) {
    var vm = this;
}

angular.module('simple.home.ratings', [
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap'
])
    .config(config)
    .controller('RatingsCtrl', RatingsCtrl)

;
```

search_filter.js

```
function config($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('simple.home.search_filter', {
            views: {
                'search_filter': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/home/search_filter/search_filter.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'SearchFilterCtrl as vm'
                }
            }
        })
}

function SearchFilterCtrl(){
    var vm = this;
}

angular.module('simple.home.search_filter', [
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap'
])
    .config(config)
    .controller('SearchFilterCtrl', SearchFilterCtrl)

;
```

Here's what I'm seeing currently. What am I messing up here?

http://i988.photobucket.com/albums/af6/jtbitt/Screen%20Shot%202015-11-18%20at%2012.58.01%20PM_zps4xgdammm.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not loading because you're creating named subviews but are trying to get your states to load.

Just use `<div ui-view></div>` and it should load.

When defining your states you need to give them a URL.
Like so:

```
.state('simple.home.search_filter', {
      url: "/search_filter",
      templateUrl: "app/home/search_filter/search_filter.tpl.html",
      ...
```

See the docs for helpful examples and explanations:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

If you want to work with named views like `<div ui-view='viewA'></div>`
You need to a more elaborate state definition

```
.state('mystate', {
  url: '/mystate',
  views: {
    'viewA': {
      template: 'path/to/viewA/template.html'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ya I've been going through the docs. The thing I'm not understanding is how I can load multiple views into one page with this method (using one <div ui-view></div>. I want both of these views to load simultaneously into the page. What am I missing here?

Comment: for nested views you need to supply a template for each view http://plnkr.co/edit/SDOcGS?p=preview